# How to ensure laravel job queue is executed after a previous one

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

Having

```
$this->dispatch(new SaveVideo($video, $api));
```

And then followed by

```
if ($user = Auth::user()) {
    $this->dispatch(new RegisterView($video['id'], $user));
}
```

In the same controller, how can I ensure that the second dispatch only happens after the first one has finished? Any ideas?

Comment: I take it that its not an option to have the second one called by the first one when its done? Might be stating the obvious but this is the simplest way surely?

Comment: already doing that, but cannot ensure that it only happens after the first one. and most of the cases 2nd job fails, because the 1st one hasn't completed

Comment: Infact check out the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues 
The Queue::after method allows you to register a callback to be executed when a queued job executes successfully. This callback is a great opportunity to perform additional logging, queue a subsequent job, or increment statistics for a dashboard.

Comment: oh, I had completely overlooked that. I will give it a try now

Comment: Hope it works as required I've added the above as an answer just to make it easier for people to read in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `Queue::after` method this should do what you require.

The [Job Completion Event documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queues#job-events) states

> The Queue::after method allows you to register a callback to be executed when a queued job executes successfully. This callback is a great opportunity to perform additional logging, queue a subsequent job, or increment statistics for a dashboard.